# how to use" would" along with"the present tense"?

Tags: tense

I am wondering if the tenses of the verbs have been used correctly. In other words, I mean, for instance, why don't we say"did rather" would"?

> Why **would** he **create** you so carefully that he even **knows** exactly how many hairs you have on your head, and then **leave** you to fend for yourself?

Extracted from [*That Is So Me*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gua0_dbhBoAC&pg=PT273&dq=%22so%20carefully%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F4mVVdWUDMrB7Aas9IqwAw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22so%20carefully%20that%22&f=false) by Nancy Rue.

Comment: Can you explain which verbs you think are wrong and why?

Comment: In this context, that of rhetoric, there's nothing wrong with the verb usage. Whether the argument is well formed or not though is another question entirely.

Comment: Hi Nima. Did you want to ask that " **In other words, I mean, for instance, why don't we say"did rather" would"?**". You can refuse corrections of other people if these corrections are not what you asked initially.

Comment: Look there [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/would): _would_ modal verb (REASON), Why would anyone do such a thing? They must have split up. Why else would he be moving out?

Answer (score 1):

The reason **would** is being used in place of **did** is to avoid asserting the premise of the statement. That is to say, **did** states that what you're questioning actually occurred and you're questioning why, where **would** merely questions why.

By shifting the tense of the word to the future, you do not acknowledge the thing in question definitely happened. Instead, you are asking hypothetically why the thing would ever occur - you are asking about the *possibility* of occurrence. For example, the meaning of these sentences is fundamentally different:

> Why would you jump off the roof?
>
> Why did you jump off the roof?

In the second case, you did jump off the roof, and you're being asked why. In the first case, you *might* have, but you might *not* have; the sentence would work in either case.

The reason for the difference is this passage is dealing with religion. Although the book seems to be supporting religion, the sentence was likely written this way to avoid sounding ham-handed.